# Full text index is not working in cloudant

Tags: json, lucene, couchdb, cloudant

Full text index search function is not working in cloudant.

Document 1 :

```
{
  "_id": "527c8d9327c6f27f17df0d2e17000530",
  "_rev": "9-4a61c6dac8d03a7d55696c3dde6a4f50",
  "employee_ID": "SCI130202",
  "proj_role": "Team Member",
  "work_total_experience": "4",
}
```

Document 2 :

```
{

  "_id": "527c8d9327c6f27f17df0d2e17000531",
  "_rev": "9-4a61c6dac8d03a7d55696c3dd46a4f50",
  "employee_ID": "SCI130201",
  "proj_role": "developer",
  "work_total_experience": "2",
}
```

Index function:

```
{ 
 "_id": "_design/search_emp",
 "_rev": "3-4562324d684a2f13d2a1f6f570736e7e",
 "views": {},
 "language": "javascript",
 "indexes": {
    "by_employee": {
      "analyzer": "standard",
      "index": "function(doc){index(doc.proj_role,{'field':'project_role'})index(doc.work_total_experience,{'field':'work_experience'})}"
    }}}
```

If am passing in URL like : `https://{username}.cloudant.com/databasename/_design/search_emp/_search/by_employee?q=project_role:developer & work_experience:2`

This only works with one condition, but i need to get exact output developer with 2 year experience details.

Comment: Can you please post an example of a document that you have in your database that you are trying to search?

Comment: Above mentioned two sample json documents.But my expected output is developer with 2 year experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me...

Here is my design doc:

```
{
    "doc": {
        "_id": "_design/search_emp",
        "_rev": "17-e7f119c21ca21cc6ac44c5a967cd5550",
        "indexes": {
            "by_employee": {
                "analyzer": "standard",
                "index": "function(doc) {\n    index('project_role', doc.proj_role, {});\n    index('work_experience', doc.work_total_experience, {});\n}"
            }
        },
        "language": "javascript",
        "views": {}
    },
    "id": "_design/search_emp",
    "key": "_design/search_emp",
    "value": {
        "rev": "17-e7f119c21ca21cc6ac44c5a967cd5550"
    }
}
```

The URL:

```
https://username.cloudant.com/databasename/_design/search_emp/_search/by_employee?include_docs=true&q=work_experience:%222%22%20AND%20project_role:developer
```

**NOTE**: I had to have double quotes around the experience value.  `work_experience:"2"` worked for me, but `work_experience:2` didn't work.

The response:

```
{
    "bookmark": "g2wAAAABaANkABxkYmNvcmVAZGIyLm1lYWQuY2xvdWRhbnQubmV0bAAAAAJiQAAAAGJ_____amgCRj_bxezgAAAAYQBq",
    "rows": [
        {
            "doc": {
                "_id": "90958a20a020a7483d3311a156fcf571",
                "_rev": "1-795df1c239d3d029eaa6d8c45ef70a8c",
                "employee_ID": "SCI130201",
                "proj_role": "developer",
                "work_total_experience": "2"
            },
            "fields": {},
            "id": "90958a20a020a7483d3311a156fcf571",
            "order": [
                0.4339554011821747,
                0
            ]
        }
    ],
    "total_rows": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So there are two issues here, one in how you're defining the index and one in how you query it.

1. you're calling `index(doc.proj_role,{'field':'project_role'});` but I'm not sure that's correct syntax; I believe you want: `index("project_role", doc.proj_role);`
2. the `&` between the two conditions should be `AND`: `q=project_role:developer AND work_experience:2`

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried above method.Am getting result but am not able to get exact result. AND condition is not working

Comment: `AND` does work. Just tried the interactive sample: https://cloudant.com/for-developers/search/ where I can search for e.g. `class:bird AND diet:carnivore`